# Getting null response during replay

Tags: jmeter

During replay of "signup" scenario in Jmeter getting `null` response for "user details" request.
Total 4 samplers:

```
Homepage, 
click new registration, 
user details, 
redirect to homepage
```

`jsessionid` and `tokenid` are generating in the first sampler response, but no dynamic value is recorded in the subsequent requests. Anyhow I have extracted the dynamic values from first sampler using RegEx Extractor. After executing the script in the sampler results of "user details" sampler I am getting the following data and response data is `null`:

```
Size in bytes: 153
Sent bytes:861
Headers size in bytes: 153
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "user details" request, are you receiving a "302" response code? If so, make sure to check the checkbox "Follow Redirects" which should be in the HTTP Request of the "user details" request.